# How can I get the number of requests to rest server with prometheus?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I have a get request like this:

```
http://localhost:4567/hello
```

Which return in postman : "hello"

I want now to receive this in prometheus:

```
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: /hello
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:4567']
```

But I receive in the prometheus console:

> level=warn ts=2019-08-06T08:25:36.643Z caller=scrape.go:937 component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=prometheus target=http://localhost:4567/hello msg="append failed" err="\"INVALID\" is not a valid start token"

If I test in prometheus a graph with:

```
prometheus_http_requests_total
```

I receive no datas.

Anybody knows what I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're scraping metrics from wrong path. You said that `GET` request on `http://localhost:4567/hello` return you `hello` instead of the metrics information.

The expected metrics information format is the following:

```sh
$ curl http://localhost:8080/metrics
# HELP http_requests_total Count of all http requests
# TYPE http_requests_total counter
http_requests_total{code="0",method="GET"} 1
http_requests_total{code="0",method="Post"} 1
# HELP version Version information about this binary
# TYPE version gauge
version{version="v0.0.1"} 0
```

Make sure which endpoint exposing your metrics information. Then update the `scrape_config`.

Comment: http://localhost:4567/metrics return 404, because no route exist with this path? Or should I send anything from the server side?

Comment: Obviously, you need to expose metrics from server side. This is how prometheus works. You expose metrics from your server side. Prometheus scrape them from you at a given endpoint.